# Issue trying to solve 404 status error code on servlet GET request

Tags: servlets, http-status-code-404

Once again thanks for the help on previous help.  Anyway I try to move on to my EFTscreen.java code to get my Search buttons to work.   In my JSP page I have the following search button with the following function call (hope I get parathesis pasting this:

```
<button id="searchEFT" class="btn smBtn">Search</button>

 xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 if (Cmd_Sched_Number != "") 
    {
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

     if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
        {
          document.getElementById("EFTSumList").innerHTML = http.responseText;
           }
        };                        

     xmlhttp.open("GET","/servlet/EFTscreen?method=searchSched&Schedule_Number=" 
                  + Cmd_Sched_Number + "&Contract_Year=" + Cmd_Contract_Year,true);
     xmlhttp.send();
   }
```

Now in looking around I was told that I need to create the servlet name and classs in the web.xml file located the WEB-INF directory of project

```
 <?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'windows-1252'?>
 <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
     version="3.0">

<servlet>
  <display-name>EFTscreen</display-name>
  <servlet-name>EFTscreen</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>eftproject.EFTscreen</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>EFTscreen</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/servlet/EFTscreen</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

here is my declaration in the EFTscreen.java file to supposedly pull the Httpservlet (removed some of the imports because it is already too big a question)

```
package eftproject;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

@WebServlet(name = "EFTscreen", urlPatterns = { "/servlet/EFTscreen"})

public class EFTscreen extends HttpServlet {   }
```

When I try running this going through debugging, I am getting the 404 error in the xmlhttp.status field not being able to find the URL.   The readystate fields are working but not sure if that is relevant.

Can you review to see what I am missing here or incorrectly?  I am thinking it is something with my url-pattern in web.xml and how I am accessing it but maybe it is something even worse.

Thanks for the help

Comment: try removing the line `@WebServlet(...blah...)`

Comment: plz post catalina.out log to trace root cause

Comment: How do I access this catalina.out log?  I am using JDeveloper to run my things.   Also if I remove the @WebServlet line I would think I would remove the extends part.  Am I wrong on that?

Comment: You don't need both a definition of the servlet in web.xml, and a @WebServlet annotation in your Servlet, either one is good but as they are the same it should not affect anything. What is the context root of your app?

Comment: I assume that in JDeveloper I would find that in my Project Properties section under Java EE Application.  Right now under Web Application Name and Web Context Root it is 'EFTProject' to match my project name.  My WLS Command Line is '${jvm} ${java.options}'.

Comment: Try adding the context root to the GET request in your jsp.

Comment: So are you saying that in the GET I should extend the directory to show EFTproject/servlet/EFTscreen?   I already have the package in the EFTscreen.java file but I don't think I am getting there anyway.

Comment: Not 100% familiar with XMLHttpRequest but the url could be absolute or relative. Probably start the URL with a "/" and it is absolute and without a "/" and it is relative. I am not sure what url you use to get to the jsp but you could try removing the leading "/" for the get request, or adding the context root, so /EFTProject/Servlet/EFTScreen. Just things to try.